# Nested Maps for Next getStaticPaths Params

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, nested, next.js

Imagine your data structure is like :

```
data = {
  "cse": {
    "first": [
      "Computer Hardware Essentials",
      "Computer System Essentials",
      "Cultural Education"
    ],
    "second": [
      "Discrete Mathematics",
      "Linear Algebra",
      "Engineering Physics - A",
    ],
    "third": [
      "Numerical Methods",
      "Optimization Techniques",
      "Digital Electronics",
    ],
    "fourth": [
      "Probability and Random Processes",
      "Data Structures and Algorithms",
      "Theory of Computation"
   ]
     }
   }
```

And you have the following route `/[semester]/[subject]` so the Next.js structure folder is: `[semester]/[subject].js`

How will we integrate through the data so that we can get the getStaticPaths params in a single nested loop?

Required Data :

```
[
{ params: {semester: "first", subject: "computer-hardware-essentials"}},
{ params: {semester: "first", subject: "computer-system-essentials"}},
{ params: {semester: "first", subject: "cultutal-education"}},
{ params: {semester: "second", subject: "discrete-mathemetics"}},
{ params: {semester: "second", subject: "linear-algebra"}},
{ params: {semester: "second", subject: "engineering-physics-a"}},
{ params: {semester: "third", subject: "numerical-methods"}},
{ params: {semester: "third", subject: "optimization-techniques"}},
{ params: {semester: "third", subject: "digital-electronics"}},
{ params: {semester: "fourth", subject: "probability-and-random-process"}},
{ params: {semester: "fourth", subject: "data-structure-and-algorithms"}},
{ params: {semester: "fourth", subject: "theory-of-computation"}}
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loop through the object using [for...in](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) and then loop the inner array using [forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) to
add each subject to an array:

```
const results = [];
for (const x in data.cse) {
  data.cse[x].forEach((s) => {
    results.push({
      params: {
        semester: x,
        subject: s
      }
    });
  });
}
```

```js
const data = {
  "cse": {
    "first": [
      "Computer Hardware Essentials",
      "Computer System Essentials",
      "Cultural Education"
    ],
    "second": [
      "Discrete Mathematics",
      "Linear Algebra",
      "Engineering Physics - A",
    ],
    "third": [
      "Numerical Methods",
      "Optimization Techniques",
      "Digital Electronics",
    ],
    "fourth": [
      "Probability and Random Processes",
      "Data Structures and Algorithms",
      "Theory of Computation"
    ]
  }
}

const results = [];
for (const x in data.cse) {
  data.cse[x].forEach((s) => {
    results.push({
      params: {
        semester: x,
        subject: s
      }
    });
  });
}

console.info(results);
```

Answer (score 0):

Using functional methods you can loop over `entries` of `data.cse` and then chain with `.flatMap`

```js
const result = Object.entries(data.cse).flatMap(([key, value]) => {
  return value.map(i => {
    return { 
      params: {
        semester: key,
        subject: i.toLowerCase().replaceAll(' ', '-')
      }
    }
  })
})
```